# Are there any sorcerer spells that can snuff torches?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, sorcerer

Points of interest

- I have dark-vision
- I'm an 11th level sorcerer
- We are preparing to split up while taking on a keep for in game reasons.
- I've saved up enough to buy a page of spell knowledge of 5th level or lower, but I'd rather not spend that much if I'm able.
- We have 66 days to prepare, have things crafted etc before we miss our chance.
- There shouldn't be any spellcasters in the area I'm to take care of. (i.e no light spells)

Okay my party and I are about to head into a keep that we have scouted out the inside of before. There are not going to be any windows on the level I need to take care of but there are a lot of torches. The people in the keep don't have any form of darkvision to my knowledge.

I'm looking for a magic item or a spell with a duration I'm able to cast that will keep snuffing out the light sources at a range where normal vision won't be able to pick me up. I'll admit I'm looking for something that will snuff the fire instead of just using darkness for two reasons, 1 so they are not re illuminating after I pass them and 2 I use some fear based spells and my GM encourages me to "set the mood" for the fear magic and I think fires literally ether slowly dying or getting blown out quickly will have such an effect... So in short RP reasons. I've been looking at wind based magic but haven't found any wind based one that actually put out flames.

I've been and will be busy until a day before our session so it may be a bit lazy of me to ask here for ideas but google didn't pull up anything but a 3rd party cantrip called "Snuff", but I don't like using 3rd party stuff and the cantrip isn't a "Cast once and just let it work for awhile" I'd have to cast it on each light source. and honestly I don't have the time to do any deeper diving so I came here.

Comment: 60 ft. would take care of most of the hallways, but that 50% chance might hurt if it doesn't proc. and yeah not very stealthy but it's an option, thanks

Comment: @JohnW. [please don’t answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Comment: I used a comment because I'm not very experienced w/ Pathfinder and didn't consider it a full answer. Noted though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There are a number of spells that extinguish torches

A number of sorcerer spells that can extinguish mundane torches:

- [Drench](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/rare-cantrips/#Drench)<sup>1</sup>, lvl 0 (rare cantrip), can extinguish fires in large or smaller objects or creatures
- [Hydraulic Push](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hydraulic-push/), lvl 1, can soak 1 square at close range(75ft for you) including extinguishing torches
- [Dust of Twilight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dust-of-twilight/), lvl 2, showers particles that cling to and snuff out mundane light in a 10ft spread at medium range(210ft for you)
- [Gust of Wind](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gust-of-wind/), lvl 2, blasts air in a 60 ft line extinguishing most mundane light sources (50% chance if they are covered)
- [Pyrotechnics](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/pyrotechnics/), lvl 2, turns a fire source at medium range (210ft for you) into fireworks or a cloud of smoke, extinguishing the fire (note the cloud also blocks your own darkvision)
- [Sleet Storm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sleet-storm/), lvl 3, is a bit flashy but causes a  40-ft. radius, 20 ft. high cylinder of flames to be extinguished (and icy floor, and also blocks your own darkvision so not ideal), at long range (840ft for you)
- [Rope Tornado](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/rope-tornado/), lvl 4, causes a blast of wind on a 120 ft line, extinguishing flames, with some more side effects
- [Hurricane Blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hurricane-blast/), lvl 4, is only a 25 ft burst from you so again not ideal but also extinguishes flames (protected flames at 50%)
- [Aqueous Orb](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/aqueous-orb/)<sup>2</sup>, lvl 4, creates a sphere of water that you can move around to put out flames. At a movement of 30 ft a round it may get spotted but it has the advantage of lasting 1 round/caster level
- [Control Winds](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/control-winds/)<sup>1</sup>, lvl 5, lasts for a 10 min/caster level and affects a large area (however, it is not on the sorcerer list which could be a problem)

None of these options seem to be exactly what you need but you can probably use some of these or a combination of them with other spells (such as invisibility to help you get closer) to get what you want.

In the spirit of teaching a man to fish, here is the [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=uKItXZaaLoOwacWmp5AI&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.d20pfsrd.com%2Fmagic%2Fall-spells%2F+extinguish&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.d20pfsrd.com%2Fmagic%2Fall-spells%2F+extinguish) I used to make this list:

> site:https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/ extinguish

You may notice that there are some more spells found this way from other classes but none of them struck me as particularly interesting over your sorcerer options.

### Magic items

- A [Rod of Delumination](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-delumination/) is a bit pricey at 35,000 gp but seems to do exactly what you want.
- The more accessible [Rod of Flame Extinguishing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-flame-extinguishing/) at 15,000 gp would work but requires you to touch the flame with it.

---

<sup>1. Found by [Ifusaso](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28326/ifusaso)</sup>

<sup>2. Found by [the dark wanderer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/14848/the-dark-wanderer), who also suggested using the word "quench" when searching</sup>

Comment: eh looks like none of the options have a duration longer then instant, but i can use my echoing spell rod with them, i'll probably go for dust of twilight as it is the least noticeable. and thank you for the tip on the search :D.

Comment: @Firealarm Hey thanks for accepting so quickly but this is usually not reccomended as other people may yet come up with better solutions, up to you though (also note that I am still looking through a bunch of magic items that may also help)

Comment: well i needed the answer before yesterday (that is how little time i had XD ) so since i went with it then i should accept the answer shouldn't i? by the way the touches going out worked perfectly, along with sound illusions the guards were already a bit scared before i used fear spells so i was able to get them to frightened :D they thought so darkness monster was coming to eat them or something. Eventually all of the guards got herded and cornered so i used aoe magic to finish em off.....

Comment: i'l be using this method in the future (i think it will work in many situations so long as the targets don't have dark vision) so if you do find such an item that means i won't have to use spell slots in the future which would be a great help.
So again thank you :thumbsup: